# Java applet strange runtime performance difference

Tags: java, performance, applet

I have a Java applet which draws some simple animations. I am seeing a massive difference in performance between these two cases:

applet tag points to a local jar. Animation is quite smooth.

applet tag points to the exact same jar on a remote server. Runs many times slower.

I am NOT talking about download/startup times, it is runtime performance which is the problem.

I am confused because I thought that once the applet had been downloaded it is running locally anyway, so what is the difference?

Server code:

```
<applet 
 archive="Projects/atmaths_applet/dist/atmaths_applet.jar, 
 Projects/atmaths_applet/dist/lib/atmcore.jar"
 code="com/example/maths/applet/Main.class" width="600" height="400">
  <param name="script" value="a.axs"/>
</applet>
```

Local code:

```
<applet archive="/axs/atmaths_applet.jar, /axs/lib/atmcore.jar"
 code="com/example/maths/applet/Main.class"
 width="600" height="400">
  <param name="script" value="/axs/a.axs" />
</applet>
```

Comment: Can you show code on how you test both scenarios?

Comment: Check the amount of memory allowed for the JVM on both machines .. ie JAVA_OPTS, Xmx 2. The speed between the two machines can be a factor.  That is how the applet communicates back to the client.

Comment: Have I misunderstood, I thought for an applet it is downloaded from the server then runs locally. In both cases it is the same client. The applet doesn't interact with anything else, it just sits in a loop and paints.

Comment: You are right it gets cached.  I remember working on a project that had to communicate with a db I think outside its environment.

Comment: Just one thing which occurred to me, it isn't a signed applet. Is it possible the local one is trusted but the remote one isn't? Could that affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running Java2D applications (including the Swing demo in the JDK) via X-Windows and it is VERY slow.  If I use VNC or nomachine to the same system, the performance is smooth as expected.

Comment: This is a different situation, the applet runs on the client, it is downloaded from the server first. That is why it is so confusing, same jar file running on the same client in the same browser.

Comment: Perhaps one is run as `-client` and the other `-server` ??

Comment: @Peter I think that last comment speaks to the real cause and should be part of the answer.

Comment: @Andrew I don't understand what you mean by this. Are you saying that the applet is running on the server? I don't see any mechanism for that, or where the -server and -client flags would be applied?

Comment: The `-client` and `-server` are just examples of flags which might be different but can result in siginificantly different behaviour.

Comment: Not sure if I am being a bit slow, flags in what? All I can set is the values in the applet element in the html page.